# Split a dataframe based on certain column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a DF like this:

| Mean 1 | Mean 2 | Stat 1 | Stat 2 | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 10 | 15 | 20 | Z |
| 3 | 6 | 9 | 12 | X |

Now, I want to split the dataframe to separate the data based on whether it is a #1 or #2 for each ID.
Basically I would double the amount of rows for each ID, with each one being dedicated to either #1 or #2, and a new column will be added to specify which number we are looking at. Instead of Mean 1 and 2 being on the same row, they will be listed in two separate rows, with the # column making it clear which one we are looking at. What's the best way to do this? I was trying pd.melt(), but it seems like a slightly different use case.

| Mean | Stat | ID | # |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 15 | Z | 1 |
| 10 | 20 | Z | 2 |
| 3 | 9 | X | 1 |
| 6 | 12 | X | 2 |

Answer (score 3):

Use [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
new_df = pd.wide_to_long(
    df, stubnames=['Mean', 'Stat'], i='ID', j='#', sep=' '
).reset_index()
```

`new_df`:

```
  ID  #  Mean  Stat
0  Z  1     5    15
1  X  1     3     9
2  Z  2    10    20
3  X  2     6    12
```

---

Or [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) then [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) the columns then [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) if order must match the OP:

```
new_df = df.set_index('ID')
new_df.columns = new_df.columns.str.split(expand=True)
new_df = new_df.stack().rename_axis(['ID', '#']).reset_index()
```

`new_df`:

```
  ID  #  Mean  Stat
0  Z  1     5    15
1  Z  2    10    20
2  X  1     3     9
3  X  2     6    12
```

Comment: You are a legend! Props for the super elegant solution and quick reply.

Comment: How would you change this code to work if there were even more columns? Ie. in addition to the ID column let's say there is one more column that we want to copy but not split.

Comment: For `wide_to_long` add any columns to "save" to `i` -> `i=['ID', 'Col1', 'Col2', ...]` for `set_index` it would be `.set_index(['ID', 'Col1', 'Col2', ...]`

Comment: Awesome! I simplified my example for the sake of the question, but technically I have like ~20 more columns I want to do that for. Would I have to manually enumerate them all?

Comment: You could slice columns: like `i=df.columns[4:]` (for the posted code) would take all columns after id (index 4 forward)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `melt` and `pivot`:

```
df = df.melt(id_vars=['ID'], value_name='Mean')
df[['variable', '#']] = df['variable'].str.split(expand=True)
df = (df.assign(idx=df.groupby('variable').cumcount())
      .pivot(index=['idx', 'ID', '#'], columns='variable').reset_index().drop(('idx', ''), axis=1))
df.columns = [col[0] if col[1] == '' else col[1] for col in df.columns]
df
Out[1]: 
  ID  #  Mean  Stat
0  Z  1     5    15
1  X  1     3     9
2  Z  2    10    20
3  X  2     6    12
```